# Multiple games on ipad

Tags: game-center, clash-of-clans

we are 4 friends and all have games on their iPads that are the same games. How do I get the accounts squared away so they are no playing each others game? For example, everyone has "Clash of the clans" on their iPads and they all play the same game. How can we get it so each person can create their own world in the game and not interfere with each others' game?

Answer (score 0):

Each person needs their own Game Center Account (and thus each needs a unique Apple ID).